# I Want to Grab the Event Values... What can I use instead of Event.srcElement?

Tags: javascript

I Want to Grab the Event Values.
What can I use instead of Event.srcElement?

```
//Take Values from our Form Input
function updateCountdown(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    countdownTitle = e.srcElement[0].value
    countdownDate = e.srcElement[1].value
    console.log(countdownTitle, countdownDate)
}
```

Comment: `srcElement` is just a single element. Why are you treating it as an array?

Comment: Needs more information. How are you calling `updateCountdown`? What are you expecting `srcElement` to be? Have you looked at [the documentation for the Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) There are hundreds of different types of events.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the value of event, you can do `event.target.value` or `e.target.value` in your case. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement) it is the best approach.

But if you want to grab the values from `inputs` on submitting the form you  should use method `elements` : `form.elements["name of an input"].value`

I've created simple form to demonstrate this in action: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-saha-mx678b?file=/src/index.js:138-165)

Comment: I tried that e.target[0].value
But it didn't work.
Im this Project the 0 => Title | 1 => Date, both of them from a Form!